# Changing color of all bar button items at once in iOS StoryBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I updated XCode and now see that all the BarButtons have a blue color on iOS7 when built with XCode 5. When I run it on a iOS6 device it remains white.

The app currently in the App Store is built for iOS5 and runs on iOS7 with white buttons on a black toolbar.

I can change all the buttons one by one from default to white color but there must be a better way to do this. Are there some options I could try without requiring minimum iOS7?

Comment: Have you tried changing the global tint colour of the storyboard?

Comment: Thank you, that sets the default back to white, does it influence any other controls in the selected storyboard?

Comment: Yes it can effect many controls, check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best fix was to replace the global tint color of the storyboard as proposed in the comments of the original question. Changing every color would also have fixed it but wouldn't be easy or futureproof.

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to edit the source of the storyboard file and **find and replace all** . For every element with a color attached to it you'll see:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" red="0.60392156860000001" green="0.8862745098" blue="0.1058823529" alpha="0.80000000000000004" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
```

Be careful not messing up your storyboard file!

Comment: I ended up changing the global tint colour of the storyboard. But this option would also work for everything that had a color defined, however a lot of the controls were using the default color so a replace wouldn't be possible for those